Is it safe to run arbitrary code in a GitHub Actions job whose GITHUB_TOKEN has no permissions?
I want to create a workflow to automatically run user-provided test functions from issues. If I disable all GITHUB_TOKEN permissions for that job, is there anything else I should worry about? I.e., when GITHUB_TOKEN has no permissions, are there any other ways a malicious agent could still "attack" my repository?
GitHub's security hardening docs talks about injection attacks, but what could an injection attack achieve in this case?
For example, is the following workflow safe?
on: issues
jobs:
  test:
    permissions:
      contents: read
    timeout-minutes: 5
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: ${{ github.event.issue.body }}

Edit
Guy Incognito pointed out in the comments that the code can still perform illegal network activities like DDoS attacks. I don't know much about networking so I asked ChatGPT how to disable all network activities on a runner, and it came up with the following solution for ubuntu, macos, and windows runners. So the new question is whether the following workflow is safe:
on: issues
jobs:
  test:
    permissions:
      contents: read
    timeout-minutes: 5
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Block outgoing traffic on Ubuntu
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: |
          sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP
          sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
      - name: Block outgoing traffic on Windows
        if: runner.os == 'Windows'
        run: |
          New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block All Outgoing Traffic" -Direction Outbound -Action Block -Enabled True
          New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow Loopback Traffic" -Direction Outbound -Action Allow -RemoteAddress 127.0.0.1 -Enabled True
      - name: Block outgoing traffic on macOS
        if: runner.os == 'macOS'
        run: |
          sudo pfctl -E
          echo "block all" | sudo pfctl -f - 
          echo "pass on lo0" | sudo pfctl -f -
          sudo pfctl -sr
      - run: ${{ github.event.issue.body }}


That sounds like a terrible idea. Even if an attacker couldn't directly do anything with the repo, you're still essentially giving public access for anyone to do anything they want with a workflow instance that runs in your repo and in your account.

@GuyIncognito Well I can give the job a timeout, and also only run the job if the user has not opened another issue in the past N hours. What's the worst that can happen? Also, I'm using the GitHub provided runners that everyone has access to; why would they want to run something on my runner when they can run it on their own?

Off the top of my head, someone uses the runner as a part of a DDOS attack, distributing illegal material, or any other illegal or TOS-breaking activity, and your account gets banned because of that.

@GuyIncognito Oh shoot, you're right! I haven't thought about that; I guess I'm too romantic for this world. Is there a way to restrict internet access of the job? And if so, would there be any other vulnerabilities then?
